# Change CSS properties when the element passes a specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my page contains a header which stays on top of a dark image. The image is the exact same size as the viewport from the browser.

My goal is, when I scroll down the page and the header passes the image completely, that the background-color of the header changes.

Is that possible - and how?

Thanks

Comment: please show your html or create a jsfiddle.net (it is possible!)

Comment: Similar to <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434735/change-css-after-a-certain-amount-of-scroll>

Comment: I've seen someone use CSS `background-attachment` for this. Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can done it by using jquery's "scrollTop":

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > sumValue) { 
        $('#header').css('background', 'yellow');
    }
})
```

"sumValue" refer the amount of scroll you want the user to travel until you change the background.

Comment: This code does not work. I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: sumValue is not defined"

Comment: instead of "sumValue" you should enter the amount of scroll you want the user travel until you change the background.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/ayBTg/)

```
$(function() {

  var image  = $('.image'),
      winHgt = $(window).innerHeight();

  image.css({ height: winHgt });


  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var header  = $('#header'),
        winHgt  = $(window).innerHeight();

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > winHgt) { 
      $('#header').css({ background: '#333' });
    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() < winHgt) { 
      $('#header').css({ background: '#888' });
    }

  });

});
```