# How to change the background color of the heading from transparent to paint white?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, header, background-color

In the following codes, the header color is transparent. I want to change its color to "#FFF" ***as I scroll down the page***. Please guide me how I can write the relevant js code for it.

Also, could it be done by plain css?

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
#home {
  background-color: red;
}
header {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: ffffff;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<header>Top Navigation</header>
<div id="home" class="sect"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434735/change-element-style-on-page-scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pen](http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/zBvyrV) Try this. It should help you. You should be doing it with either jquery or plain javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function () {
//if you hard code, then use console
//.log to determine when you want the 
//nav bar to stick.  
console.log($(window).scrollTop())
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
$('header').css('background-color','#FFF');
 }
 if ($(window).scrollTop() < 10) {
 $('header').css('background-color','transparent');
 }
 });
});
```

Comment: what if I had a class instead of "header tag"?

Comment: $('.someclass').css('background-color','#FFF'); Use this sort of code if you want to access it with class name. Please mark the answer accepted if it works for you. It might help others.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);` ?