# Scale and move logo on scroll

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help? I am trying to scale and move the logo when scrolling down and change it back when scrolling up. I would like to change the margins and move it to top left corner.

```css
.logo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you modify and try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434786/4813913

Comment: Can you look at this example and see if you can change it to as per your need.
https://css-tricks.com/sticky-smooth-active-nav/ or https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, you must be sure to include code showing your attempts, images or descriptions of your current output, images/descriptions of your desired output, and a detailed description of the problem. See [How to Ask a Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 

With more information, more contributors to the site may be able to offer you help.